# Adding widget to flutter app causes conflicts in .yaml file

Tags: flutter, pubspec

I am trying to add a calendar widget to my flutter app but I am getting errors when I run "pub get".

pubspec.yaml content:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^1.3.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_auth_web: ^0.3.2+3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  uuid: ^2.2.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^4.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Output from pub get:
Running "flutter pub get" in tonnah...
Because tonnah depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+3 which depends on intl ^0.16.1, intl ^0.16.1 is required.
So, because tonnah depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because tonnah depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

When I change the intl: ^0.17.0  to intl:^0.16.1  I get the following output from pub get:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in tonnah...                          
Because tonnah depends on table_calendar ^3.0.0 which depends on intl ^0.17.0, intl ^0.17.0 is required.
So, because tonnah depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because tonnah depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I seem to be running in circles. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

Comment: I have done that but as I stated in my question I just get the original error message.

Comment: What about using `^0.17.0`?

Comment: If I use ^0.17.0 it tells me to use ^0.16.1. If I use ^0.16.1 it tells me to use ^0.17.0.

Comment: Did you remove `intl: ^0.17.0` from dependencies tab before adding it to `dependency_overrides`?

Comment: Yes. I replaced the version in the line each time. Here is the output when I run flutter --version:   Flutter 2.3.0-17.0.pre.34 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision de23eb7b29 (4 days ago) • 2021-05-24 15:34:02 -0400
Engine • revision b1385c0df1
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-145.0.dev)

Comment: I am having a similar issue with the test dependency.